# function not working from the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the below Jquery code the `checkBoxName.on('change', function() {` will be triggered after the second time i check the check Box, i'm calling the function `foo` in `onchange` in the check box , why is it not working from the first time i check the box ?

```
function foo (arg1,arg2,arg3) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#checkBox').on('change', function() {

      if ($('#checkBox').is(':checked')) {//this is triggered after the second time i check the box
        $('#errorDiv').removeClass(errorClass);
        $('#submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
      } else {
        $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#errorDiv').addClass(errorClass);
      }

    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping your foo function around a document ready function

Comment: @j08691 because i'm passing some args to `foo` i didn't mention here

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling `foo()` from the checkbox change event handler, then all `foo()` does is install another change handler.  It won't fire that new handler on the current event.

It's also a bit odd that you're wrapping things inside of `foo` with `$(document).ready()`.  I don't know if that's causing problems or not, but it is not the usual way of doing things which suggests you may be trying to do something unusual that you have not explained.

Probably, you just want the checkbox handler installed from the beginning:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#checkBox').on('change', function () {

        if ($('#checkBox').is(':checked')) { //this is triggered after the second time i check the box
            $('#errorDiv').removeClass(errorClass);
            $('#submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
            $('#submitBtn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('#errorDiv').addClass(errorClass);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is for the wrapper function which is called on first change.

just remove it then everything would be OK.

```js
$('#check-me').on('change', function(e) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('#checked').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#unchecked').addClass('hidden');
  } else {
    $('#checked').addClass('hidden');
    $('#unchecked').removeClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check-me" />Check me
</label>
<div class="hidden" id="checked">Checked</div>
<div class="hidden" id="unchecked">Un Checked</div>
```

Comment: So how to call it in`onchange` in the checkbox , because i'm passing some other args to the function i didn't mentioned here

Comment: @Sherif there is no need to call it on change you're binding this to change of `#checkBox` so it will automatically called every time the `change event` fired.